# Convergence of the series using power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following series converge or diverge?

1)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n}}{n^{\frac2n}}$$

2)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n} (\ln n)^2}{n^{\frac12}}$$

I am trying to use the power series to do a direct comparison test and solve both of these questions. However the negative values in the numerator is throwing me off, i can't seem to find the right value to compare. Anyone could point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: "I have two questions" What are they?

Comment: @Did The two questions which i have numbered as Qn1 and Qn2. "I have two questions" = "I am given two questions to solve".

Comment: The things labelled Qn1 and Qn2 are not questions, but formulas of quantities depending on $n$.

Comment: @Did Ah..okay, i get what you mean now. My mistake :)

Comment: Still no question in Qn1 and Qn2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Notice that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2/n}}=1\ne0$$
so the first series is divergent.

For the second series let
$$g(x)=\frac{(\ln x)^2}{\sqrt x}$$
then using the derivative prove that this function is increasing (to $0$) for a sufficient large $x$ and conclude the convergence of this series using the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: The first series does not converge.

Comment: Nice work, Sami!

Answer (score 1):

Both series are so called alternating series. For them a very nice test shows if they converge. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test) is the link to it.

For the first series, you may encounter some problems. Take a look at what the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac2n}}$$ is.

Comment: The first one is not alternating. Recall that the general term of an alternating series (1) goes to zero and (2) is decreasing in absolute value.

Comment: @Did It is alternating. By definition (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series), any series which has elements which switch their sign is alternating. What you described is the conditions that must be filled for an alternating series to be convergent.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n^{\frac 2n}}=1,$$
so
$$\frac{{(-1)}^{n}}{n^{\frac2n}}\not\to 0$$
and the first series does not converge.